# catch return value after execute external task using AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges

Tags: objective-c, macos

I was managed to execute an external task on a different process (child proc) using the method AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges in the following manner :

```
AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(
     AuthorizationRef, 
     commandFullPath, 
     Flags, 
     Arguments, 
     &CommunicationsPipe)
```

However, I'd also like obtain the return value from that specific command. in bash it's saved in the special character $?. is there any equivalent in objective C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for sub-process pid using the communication file you supplied to `AuthorisationExecuteWithPrivileges` in the following command :

```
FILE* pipe = NULL; 
int status = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(auth, path, flags, args, &pipe)
if (status == errAuthorizationSuccess)
    pid_t pid = fcntl(fileno(pipe), F_GETOWN, 0);
```

Then you can use the pid and wait till the sub-process returns and acquire its return value :

```
pid_t pid2 = 0;
while ((pid = waitpid(pid, &stat, WNOHANG)) == 0) { }
int terminationStatus = WEXITSTATUS(stat);
```